# How to use the insertColumn(int j, vector column)

Tags: java, arrays

I just need to insert rows and columns of zeros in a matrix

tried to get exmples from web searches

```java
ArrayList<double [][]> al = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i1= 0; i1<=i; i1++)
    al.add(k);

System.out.println(al.size());
double[][] firstMatrix = al.get(i);
double [][] matrix1 = al.get(i); 
double [][] matrix2 = al.get(i); 
Matrix Matrix1 = new Matrix (matrix1);
Matrix1.show();
System.out.println(); 
Matrix1.insertColumn(0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
Matrix1.show();
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Which class is `Matrix`?

Comment: I just need to know how to input the vector column eg. insertColumn(0,{0,0,0,0}???

Comment: Please follow Java code conventions. Variable names should *always* start with a lowercase letter. Only start names of types (classes, interfaces, enums) with an Uppercase letter. In particular, don't do something like name one variable `matrix1` and another `Matrix1`. It makes your code unreadable.

Comment: I'm sorry Lutz, very dumb in java, What do you mean "class of Matrix"

Comment: Noted RealSkeptic, will fix but still trying to insert rows and columns with zeros

Comment: You define `Matrix Matrix1`. That means the object `Matrix1` is of type `Matrix`. But this is not a standard Java type. We know nothing about it, and we can't help you unless you bring us its definition (in the question itself, unless it's part of a standard library).

Answer (score 0):

Your question boils down to adding a new column/row to a Java array. This is not possible per se, because your array has an exact memory area allocated to it and you would need a larger memory area for the resulting array, so, the solution is to create a new array and solve the problem that way:

Adding a row

```
double[][] addRow(double[][] input, int where) {
    double[][] output = new double[input.length + 1][input[0].length];
    for (int rIndex = 0; rIndex < output.length; rIndex++) {
        for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < output[0].length; cIndex++) {
            if (rIndex < where) output[rIndex][cIndex] = input[rIndex][cIndex];
            else if (rIndex == where) output[rIndex][cIndex] = 0;
            else output[rIndex][cIndex] = input[rIndex - 1][cIndex];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Adding a column

```
double[][] addColumn(double [][]input, int where) {
    double[][] output = new double[input.length][input[0].length + 1];
    for (int rIndex = 0; rIndex < output.length; rIndex++) {
        for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < output[0].length; cIndex++) {
            if (cIndex < where) output[rIndex][cIndex] = input[rIndex][cIndex];
            else if (cIndex == where) output[rIndex][cIndex] = 0;
            else output[rIndex][cIndex] = input[rIndex][cIndex - 1];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

and make sure you assign the result of these methods to whatever variable/member you have used as the data source.

Comment: Thanks Lajos!! its a mouthful, let me absorb and comeback later. Just a dumb question, why not insertColumn(i, vector column)??

Comment: @PhillipOosthuizen you can do it that way as well. In our case for the sake of simplicity I assumed that adding a column/row means adding an empty row, column. If you intend to add a non-empty row/column, then you will just need to assign its values to the corresponding target (a.k.a the new column/row). If my answer solved the problem in your question, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.